# Why doesn't CodeIgniter's XSS filter clean all?

Tags: codeigniter, xss

Why does CodeIgniter's XSS filter only react through regular expressions on specific things instead of sanitizing all input in the first place regardless if the content is tainted or not? Also, why is this done during input and not on output (like it's supposed to be?)

Answer (score 8):

> Why does CodeIgniter's XSS filter only react through regular expressions on specific things instead of sanitizing all input in the first place regardless if the content is tainted or not?

This doesn't make much sense. How are we to tell whether or not something is "tainted" without checking it first?

By the definition of CI's [`xss_clean()`](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/72bf2f06cb5d/system/core/Security.php#cl-211), we don't ***always*** want to sanitize input. As you mentioned, it's the output that matters - and that's where we need to be mindful of [XSS atacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). If we *always* "sanitize" input with CI's `xss_clean()`, then how would I, for one example, be able to post javascript or PHP code examples on my blog, or let users do it in the comments? It would end up getting `[removed]`.

> Also, why is this done during input and not on output (like it's supposed to be?)

You do have the option to enable the global xss filter in your CI config, which will run `xss_clean()` on `$_POST`, `$_GET`, and `$_COOKIE` data automatically before you can get your hands on it. This is the lowest level possible to protect you from yourself, bu the option is always available to instead clean the data explicitly. For example:

```
// With the Input class on $_POST data
$this->input->post('username', TRUE); // Second parameter runs xss_clean

 // Using the Security class on any data
$this->security->xss_clean($username);

// Using the Form Validation class to automatically clean the input
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', '', 'xss_clean');
```

Since you could still simply use `$_POST['username']` instead, by enabling the global filter it will already be xss_cleaned for you. This is the lazy way to do it, and unfortunately once those globals are cleaned, there's no way to undo it.

If you are already aware of when and where XSS attacks can happen - you have the function easily available to use if you wish. Keep in mind that this does *not* magically make all data "safe", it merely prevents some of the more malicious code injection. Something more harmless like `</div>` will get past this filter. You should always be sanitizing input explicitly in an appropriate way for the context in which it is used.

Comment: is it okay to have global xss filter turned on and at the same time still xss_clean() explicitly where applicable?

Comment: If you're talking about direct use of get, post, and cookie: then it's pointless - the filter runs on those things automatically if globally enabled. You should still use it though, just remember that the vector for XSS is anywhere that javascript can be run. It won't hurt you when printing to Excel or a text file, for example. I always say filter *output*, not input. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674848/codeigniter-input-filtering/9675233#9675233

Comment: ...that being said, it won't hurt you to do it either, if that's what you're wondering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714945/is-it-okay-to-repeatedly-xss-clean-data-in-codeigniter